# Like Touch Id is it possible to use iOS Passcode lock programmatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, touch-id, passcode

I am  hoping to create an app that could automatically enable the device Passcode lock screen under certain conditions.

From google around it sounds like this may not be possible, though I never came upon a remark about "programmatically influencing Passcode" explicitly.

Could someone please confirm it if this is impossible or point me in the right direction for how this might be done if it is indeed possible?

Answer (score 1):

You may not enable the device Passcode lock screen but you can create your own interface to do just that. If you can't then you should look into Touch ID. Apple released a framework called `Local Authentication` to developers to use in iOS 8. You can do more research about it if you are using Objective-C but if you are using Swift then there are good YouTube videos that are helpful for you.